# Is there a way to make the emoticon expressed in the EditTextView appear the same in the TextView?

Tags: android, textview, emoji, emoticons

If you look at the picture, it is EditTextVIew at the top and TextView at the bottom. As you can see, the emoji are dark in the EditTextView, but slightly blurry in the TextView. In TextVIew, I want the emoticon expressed in EditTextView to be expressed. Is there a way?

[image]

Comment: I would guess that your theme there has a translucent color for `TextView` text. Try setting a fully opaque text color on the `<TextView>`; e.g., `android:textColor="#ffffffff"`.

Comment: You were right! Thank you for solving the problem.